# Can we embed XML string as JSON properties value

Tags: php, xml, json

I want to store XML string inside PHP array. The XML string should not be parsed. How to prevent PHP from parsing XML string.

```
$tooltip=array( 'headerFormat'=> '<span style="font-size:10px">{point.key}</span><table>',
                    'pointFormat'=> '<tr><td style="color:{series.color};padding:0">{series.name}: </td>' +
                        '<td style="padding:0"><b>{point.y:.1f} mm</b></td></tr>',
                    'footerFormat'=> '</table>',
                    'shared'=> true,
                    'useHTML'=> true);
    print_r($tooltip);
```

I expected the output to be;

```
Array ( [headerFormat] => '<span style="font-size:10px">{point.key}</span><table>',            [pointFormat] =>'<tr><td style="color:{series.color};padding:0">{series.name}: </td><td style="padding:0"><b>{point.y:.1f} mm</b></td></tr>'[footerFormat] =>'</table>',
[shared] => true, [useHTML] => true )
```

but I get;

```
Array ( [headerFormat] => {point.key} [pointFormat] => 0 [footerFormat] =>
[shared] => true [useHTML] => true )
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try:

```
echo htmlentities(print_r($tooltip, true));
```

The second argument to `print_r()` makes it return the formatted value instead of displaying it. And `htmlentities()` will encode the string so that all the special HTML characters will be treated as literal instead of being interpreted by the browser.

Answer (score 0):

I tried to reproduce your findings, but it seems all normal to me. As long as you quote strings with a single quote `'` they will not get parsed. You can check your output more reliably by using `var_dump`, e.i `echo var_dump($tooltip)`

Answer (score 0):

You are displaying this through the browser - this is doing the parsing.

If you view the page source then you will see the desired output.